# React Native - TextInput - How to use value & defaultValue together

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got the following Component and I want to init TextInput with defaultValue and then when user type update the value of it.

How do I do that?

Here what I've tried - but this way TextInput is always empty on initialization.

```
class Note extends Component {
    state = {
        text: ""
    };

    render() {
        const {onChange} = this.props;

        return (
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                         this.setState({text}); 
                         onChange(text);
                    }
                    value={this.state.text}
                    defaultValue={this.props.text}
                />
        );
    } }
```

"react": "^16.4.1"
"react-native": "^0.55.4",

Comment: Do you want to append the user input with Default value?

Comment: You want to update the value on text change . right ?

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @anilsidhu Yes.

Comment: @chenop i am making a  answer for make better code formatting

Comment: I faced the issue setting integer value as default. value.toString() solved my problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally solved it,

The key is the following - "value" has preceding over "defaultValue" unless "value" is undefined!

So, Init `this.state.text = undefined`, this way defaultValue can be initialized with this.props.text.

```
class Note extends Component {
    state = {
        text: undefined
    };

    render() {
        const {onChange} = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                         this.setState({text}); 
                         onChange(text);
                    }
                    value={this.state.text}
                    defaultValue={this.props.text}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I found this a bit more clean than @anilSidhu solution.

Comment: definitely best answer

Comment: I faced the issue setting integer value as default. value.toString() solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set default value in `state` itself like following:

```
class Note extends Component {
    state = {
        text: this.props.text
    };

    render() {
        const {onChange} = this.props;

        return (
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                         this.setState({text}); 
                         onChange(text);
                    }
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
        );
    } }
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it become useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering But I think that's not good enough. This way the props.text will be used only once (when constructor will be invoked) I want the props.text to be used every time it is changed.

Comment: Also please note that if Note is encapsulated by another component which is connected to Redux (my case but I think its the common case) and the encapsulated Component init the text attribute which is passed to Note - than this.props.text will be initialized in the first time with undefined.

Comment: yes you are right as I think at first time render pass blank value to `TextInput`'s `value` and then it will take `this.props.text`. may be this is the reason.

Comment: thanks for you time man - The first time this.props.text is undefined. the encapsulated component use mapStateToProps to init text but it init text only after it was pass (as undefined) to Note

Comment: its not correct because in this way render will not update on again.

Comment: Actually I used this in my project and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Note extends Component {
  state = {
    text: undefined
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ text: this.props.text })
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <TextInput
        onChange={(text) => {
          this.setState({ text: text.target.value });

        }}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**It should work for you and if you are still facing the issue let me know please**

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when you're having both `value` and `defaultValue` props, always `value` prop will take precedence and thus `defaultValue` won't be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you are showing number type to default value it doesn't work. you must convert to string type as follows:

```
defaultValue(String(this.props.text)}
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone having trouble with this problem. I've experienced it. i expect my number `Value` to be displayed on `Textinput`. But placeholders keep showing.

The solution is your `Value` must be String.
So i convert my `Number` to `String` use `toString()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Holy crap. 2022 and this is what we're dealing with. Thanks for this.